# Is there a word for the idea that wealth equals power?

Tags: single-word-requests

Until now I would just have used "capitalism" because it is somewhat understandable, but factually it is wrong, is there a better word?

Answer (score 6):

In a *plutocracy*, the wealthy rule, so *plutocratic* would describe a system where power equals wealth (and vice versa)